# Excel error, stops running macro

Tags: excel, vba

I am experiencing an odd bug on Excel. I have a macro that shows a non-modal userform when I press CTRL+m (Macro shortcut). Every once in a while, and it's not that frequent (Shows up once or twice during the day, I use the macro every 5 minutes or so), Excel won't run the macro, won't show the userform and will just beep (as in "mistake, cannot proceed executing code").

I went into the Macro window to try to press "Run" and manually execute, but all buttons are disabled, except for "Create". If you click it, it says the macro name is not valid. As you can see in the screenshot below, the name of the macro shows the instance where the code is (Sheet1 of the workbook).

Sometimes it can be fixed by saving the workbook and just re-trying, but sometimes it doesn't; when it doesn't, I run a different macro (by double clicking a specific column) that shows a modal userform, and executing its code. Then my first macro returns to normal.

Any help will be very much appreciated.

[image: Macro run window]

**Edit:** Adding the code as requested in the comments

```
Sub ShowCommentWindow()
    Dim myCell As Range
    Dim companyColumn As Long
    Dim wbk as Workbook
    Dim company as String
    Dim phone as Long

    Set wbk = ActiveWorkbook

For Each myCell In wbk.Worksheets(1).Range("A1:Q1")

   If myCell.Text = "Company" Then
        companyColumn = myCell.Column
        company = ActiveCell.Text
        phone = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 4).Value
        Exit For
    End If
Next myCell

If ActiveCell.Column = companyColumn Then

    If EmailForm.Visible Then
        GoTo ExitProc
    Else
        If Not ActiveCell.Row < 4 Then
            ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = ActiveCell.Row - 3
        Else
            ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = ActiveCell.Row
        End If
        If CommentWindow.Visible Then
            CommentWindow.AddButton.SetFocus
            CommentWindow.CommentBox.SetFocus
            Exit Sub
        Else
            CommentWindow.Show
            ManageComments
            AddComment
        End If
    End If
End If

ExitProc:
End Sub
```

**Edit2:** Posting more code, for QueryClose:

```
Private Sub UserForm_QueryClose(Cancel As Integer, CloseMode As Integer)

Dim myCell As Range
Dim isCompany As String

    If Not CommentWindow.CommentBox.Text = CommentWindow.TextCopy.Text Then
        saveConf = MsgBox("Changes have not been saved yet. Do you want to save?", vbExclamation + vbYesNoCancel + vbDefaultButton2, "Save changes?")
        If saveConf = vbYes Then
            Call SaveComment
            GoTo ExitProc
        ElseIf saveConf = vbCancel Then
            changed = True
            Cancel = 1
            CommentWindow.AddButton.SetFocus
            CommentWindow.CommentBox.SetFocus
            'CommentWindow.CommentBox.Text = CommentWindow.TextCopy.Text
        Else
            CommentWindow.TextCopy.Text = CommentWindow.CommentBox.Text
            GoTo ExitProc
        End If
    Else
        If Not changed = True Then
            GoTo ExitProc
        End If
    End If

ExitProc:
End Sub
```

Comment: At any point is your macro disabling events or screen updates, as in `Application.EnableEvents = False` and Application.ScreenUpdating = False`. If so, your macro may be in a somewhat unknown state while working through your logic. Try enabling either or both in the Immediate window in the VBA editor to see if it "unlocks" your macro.

Comment: Nope, not at all. Just checked and nothing.

Comment: This happened to me once...forget how I solved it :/ Try deleting and creating new modules.

Comment: I have a similar issue with an Excel workbook that has a couple of forms (which ARE modal). I was thinking it had to do with one of the COM objects I'm referencing or Windows Defender locking the workbook somehow (I cannot even save my workbook at that point), but that's a W.A.G. on my part.

Comment: Maybe there is a rogue thread that is looping in your script. Next time it happens I suggest you go into the Visual Basic Editor (ALT+F11), Break the code and see if its getting stuck in some part of your script in particular. Hope this helps. Cheers,

Comment: Thanks nbayly, but I don't think it's that, since when I go into the code and just run it, it does. Then I return to Excel and the shortcut is still malfunctioning.
I'm still stumped.

Comment: can we see the code on the shortcut that shows the userform?

Comment: I just edited the original post and added it.

Comment: Where is the line `GoTo ExitProc` supposed to take you? If you put a stop on `If EmailForm.Visible Then` is that form already visible and it doesn't know where to go to exit?

Comment: That was my mistake when pasting on StackOverflow. The ExitProc does exist and takes you to Exit Sub. I must have mistakenly deleted it FROM MY POST HERE, not my code.

Comment: Hmm code seems right, what I think it could be happening is that userforms are not unloaded from memory and probably that's giving you the error after a few runs in the same instance of Excel (this means re running the code without closing completely Excel). Do you unload forms as soon as they are not required? _IE: Unload(CommentWindow)_ OT: Probably you would like to add a Call Argument to Call ManageComments and Call AddComments, I've seen not doing so does random errors sometimes.

Comment: I have a Sub that saves the content from a TextBox to a Comment in a cell; the last statement in that Sub (before cleaning up Objects) is Unload CommentWindow. I also have QueryClose code that I'm posting on an edit; that does **NOT** have an Unload statement, but it was my understanding that QueryCose unloaded the form by default. Please see OP.

Comment: Close does not unload the userform, it just closes it (expected behavior), you may confirm the behavior if you show the userform after (it would have the values it did before saving -probably that gives an error somewhere-). The best approach is to always unload the userforms -close should be handled with care since it's not the same as unload, close will keep the element in memory and the "garbage collector" in excel is not 100% accurate-

Comment: Cool, I'll make that change and run tests. Will update this if it works.

Comment: @AndresFelipeMartinez did it work?

Comment: It's been working steadily for now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like the issue is not unloading the forms from ( `Unload(UserForm)` )

This leads to a [memory leak.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms859408.aspx)

[Even the official documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff845441.aspx) -this refers to Access, but, should behave the same for Excel (there's no Form object or userform documentation there)- state the Lifecycle is Unload->Deactivate->Close, and this should happen when you close the userform as well,  daily usage has shown that Unload if not stated may not be triggered when closing the userform.

The lifecycle is not that strictly monitored sometimes, but, that may lead to memory leaks and strange behaviors, always when working with objects you shouldn't rely that garbage collector will clean them if not specified. Probably adding something to confirm that [terminate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg278823.aspx) is being correctly handled will be helpful.

***EDIT***

If you're having problems remembering the unload -or still having problems with memory-, it will be a good practice to do the following:

```
Sub MyMainProcess()
Dim myform As UserForm1: Set myform = UserForm1 'this is your UserForm name
myform.Show
'my stuff needed...
Unload myform
Set myform = Nothing
End Sub
```

Unload and Nothing to clean as much as possible with coding

Comment: Nice catch @Sgdva! I went through my code and found one userform that rarely gets loaded but is never unloaded. This likely explains why my code works for weeks at a time before it becomes unresponsive and unsaveable. I might have to look for ways to improve garbage collection.

Comment: Always declare "objects" consecutive so you "remember" and spot easier at the end to set as nothing and always remember to unload userforms after retrieving the desired behavior in your sub

Comment: I do have something to add, though the code has been working without issues so far, after adding the Unload portion: this problem happened to me even when I created the first version of my macro, which used _no forms at all._ Go figure.

Comment: Are you sure you're not using another objects? This _may_ happen with all the objects that are not set as nothing after called -I don't know what could trigger it what situations are ok and what situations are out of the scope -that's why we don't let the garbage collector to figure it and set as nothing-

Answer (score 0):

I see that you're calling an "outside" macro (it's not within the active workbook) - Is it possible that then those roughly 2 times a day that it doesn't work that workbook (Database 2 Lumber.xlsm) is being used by someone else at that time (eight running that, or another macro?).

If so, What I have done before is save a local copy of the workbook each time the macro is run

Comment: That shouldn't be a factor, even if it's used by someone else that doesn't affect when running the macro -since it loads the last known stage of the archive-. OT: I've a macro on a shared drive that everyone can use without interfering in someone else work, just restricts the save in the shared drive (which again, only I can do it for code updates; this is a template mostly to fit users information but it's personal to each).

Comment: This is late, I know, but for some reason I was not notified of these answers. Anyway, to Jeremy: That was the most perplexing thing. This macro was *NOT* on a different workbook. Database 2 Lumber.xlsm *WAS* the workbook where the code resided; when the error ocurred, Excel would then show the macro as not existing. Anyway, it was solved by going through each line and making sure forms were being unloaded at the proper times, and objects were set to `Nothing` after being done with them.

Comment: Cool, glad to you fixed it - To be honest I wouldn't have figured that out because I was just reading the lines rather than trying to replicate